# Can I take GoPro videos that I have imported on to my iPad and later put them on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: ipad, mac, macbook-pro, import

I travel a lot and I use a memory card reader on my iPad to import my GoPro videos and pictures while I am traveling just because it is easier than bringing my whole MacBook along with me. Can I then later take those videos and put them onto my MacBook? I basically use my iPad as a temporary storage device that way I can get them on my MacBook to edit them and upload them appropriately (hopefully). Appreciate any help!

Comment: Neither do I have an iPad nor do I store things on my iPhone. But I think it has to be similar, as when you connect your device to your Mac either iTunes or iPhoto (whichever service you use) will open up and you can choose what data you'd like to import. I'm not sure with iTunes but you can use iPhoto to import videos (although in the application they are called photos). I can't back up my information, that's why I am not addressing it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

vkvau is essentially correct, when you sync your iPad to your Mac iPhoto should open and give you the option of importing all/selected pictures/videos and then an option to delete them.

It's all quite easy and exactly as the iPad was designed to work.